# remove some rows from data after doing groupy

Tags: python, pandas-groupby, data-analysis, drop

I have this dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'scientist':["Wendelaar Bonga"," Sjoerd E.", "Grätzel"," Michael", "Willett", "Walter C.",
                         "Kessler", "Ronald C.", "Witten, Edward", "Wang, Zhong Lin"],
           'SubjectField': ["Biomedical Engineering", "Inorganic & Nuclear Chemistry",
                            "Organic Chemistry", "Biomedical Engineering", "Developmental Biology",
                            "Mechanical Engineering & Transports", "Biomedical Engineering", "Microbiology",
                            "Cardiovascular System & Hematology", "Biomedical Engineering"]})
```

and I want to count the number of scientists in each subject field and remove subject fields that have less than 2 scientists from my data.

```
x= df.groupby('SubjectField')['scientist'].count()
ans = x[x > 2]
```

this is my code but I don't know how to remove the mentioned rows:

Comment: based out of your code `ans` will only the have rows with `count > 2` , what else do u need?

Comment: can you add expected output for above data?

Answer (score 0):

You are already on the right track , I have just added the code to drop the rows not satisfying the condition

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'scientist':["Wendelaar Bonga"," Sjoerd E.", "Grätzel"," Michael", "Willett", "Walter C.",
                         "Kessler", "Ronald C.", "Witten, Edward", "Wang, Zhong Lin"],
           'SubjectField': ["Biomedical Engineering", "Inorganic & Nuclear Chemistry",
                            "Organic Chemistry", "Biomedical Engineering", "Developmental Biology",
                            "Mechanical Engineering & Transports", "Biomedical Engineering", "Microbiology",
                            "Cardiovascular System & Hematology", "Biomedical Engineering"]})


x = df.groupby('SubjectField')['scientist'].count()
```

You can use `drop` with argument `index` to drop the rows not matching the condition

> Tilde `~` is used as the negation to fetch the opposite of a condition

```
drop_idx = x[~(x > 2)].index.values
x = x.drop(index=drop_idx)
```

`x` will only contain rows with count greater than 2

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mask = df.groupby('SubjectField')['SubjectField'].transform('count') > 2
filtered = df[mask]
```